# What is the proper way to use google's api client in ruby to get Gmail messages?

Tags: ruby, google-api

I've setup a Service Account in my google developer console and I've turned ON the Gmail API.  Using the various examples for ruby, I came up with the following script in an attempt to get at my emails:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'google/api_client'

SERVACC = "abcdefg@developer.gserviceaccount.com" # My Service Account's CLIENT ID
GAPMAIL = "myapp@mydomain.com" #gApps account
PKCFILE = "myapp.p12" # Downloaded S.A. cred file
GMSCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"
TOKEURI = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"

options = {:application_name => 'gmail', :application_version => 'v1'}
Gclient = Google::APIClient.new( options )
Gclient.authorization = Signet::OAuth2::Client.new(
  :token_credential_uri => TOKEURI,
  :audience => TOKEURI,
  :scope => GMSCOPE,
  :issuer => SERVACC,
  :signing_key => Google::APIClient::PKCS12.load_key(PKCFILE, 'notasecret')
)
Gclient.authorization.fetch_access_token!

result = Gclient.execute!(
  :api_method => Gclient.discovered_api('gmail').users.messages.list,
  :parameters => {:userId => GAPMAIL}
)
```

Unfortunately, it bombs with a Backend Error:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/google-api-client-0.8.2/lib/google/api_client.rb:654:in `block (2 levels) in execute!': Backend Error (Google::APIClient::ServerError)
        from /Users/bbialek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable/retry.rb:27:in `perform'
        from /Users/bbialek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable.rb:15:in `retriable'
        from /Users/bbialek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/google-api-client-0.8.2/lib/google/api_client.rb:635:in `block in execute!'
        from /Users/bbialek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable/retry.rb:27:in `perform'
        from /Users/bbialek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/retriable-1.4.1/lib/retriable.rb:15:in `retriable'
        from /Users/bbialek/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.4/gems/google-api-client-0.8.2/lib/google/api_client.rb:626:in `execute!'
        from stack.rb:22:in `<main>'
```

I actually see the Server errors (5xx) count going up under the API's usage, so I can't be too far of.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone found this while struggling away....

Here is a working implementation. Hope it helps. 
You'll need to have registered the app in your google developers console..etc and, importantly, granted the appropriate scopes to the service account in your google apps domain (the scope below is the full access one).

```
google_api_key = #Your API Key - here it's stored as a string, but you might want to use the file version
google_api_email = #The email id attached to your service account
account = #the email account you want to use
application_name = # a name for your app
application_version = #version for your app
  @google_mail_session = Google::APIClient.new(application_name: application_name, application_version: application_version)

  key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pem(
      google_api_key,
      'notasecret')
  asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
      google_api_email,
      ['https://mail.google.com/'],
      key
  )
  @google_mail_session.authorization = asserter.authorize(account)
  # Leave the account details out for a generic authorization, you'll need to specify the account when you make a call to the API.
  @gmail_api = @google_mail_session.discovered_api('gmail', 'v1')
```

An example call would be

```
 response = @google_mail_session.execute(
   :api_method => @gmail_api.users.messages.list, 
   :parameters => {:userId => 'me'}) # you can use the standard address here if you don't want to authorize to a specific account above
```

This took me a long, long time to get working where I largely felt like I was shooting in the dark. Why google make it so damn difficult is beyond me....